How to find and display the difference between two multivalue fileds in splunk
I have two mulitvalue fields A and B .
A has values
a
b

And B has values
b 
c

I want to list the non matching value in the two multi value fields i.e c and d .
How can I do that?

Shouldn't the non-matching fields be a and c?  There is no d.

Try this run-anywhere SPL:
| makeresults 
| eval 
    a=split("a#b", "#"),
    b=split("b#c","#") 
| eval 
    a=mvdedup(a),
    b=mvdedup(b),
    c=mvappend(a,b) 
| mvexpand c 
| stats count by c 
| where count=1

The logic is basically:

reduce a and b to unique values
append a and b into c
count the different values
if any value is present exactly once, then it is non-matching

